# Calculate age with Low Nice Date

Tags: low

Is it possible to calculate a members' age with Low Nice Date?

Experimented with this but really need to know what format the (native) {member_birthday} outputs...

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{current_time format="%F %j%S, %Y"}-{member_birthday}" format="%F %j%S, %Y"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way EE stores birthday info is in 3 separate columns in the database (ie. Month, Day & Year'), whereas a entry date or date field the value is stored in UNIX timestamp.

So, the native `{birthday}` field outputs: `Month Day, Year`

In order for this to work with `exp:low_nice_date:range` tag, you would need to format the `from` & `to` parameters correctly. At a quick glance, I don't think this is possible from the native birthday field and low nice date.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few addons at Devot-ee that may help you:

http://jeremyworboys.com/add-ons/time-difference

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cas-elapsed-time

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to calculate an age based on a date with Low Nice Date.